# Using jQuery locally with Bootstrap for Django wont respond

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have this in my `base.html` file included

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
```

And I'm using `navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light` from Bootstrap for my `navbar`.
This is working. When I'm using a small display (like smartphone) it shrinks the menu to dropdown element with a button to expand.

But the `{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}` part is taking too long to fully load the jquery source from network:
Around 400ms without cache. I would like to lose this waiting time as much as possible.
So I downloaded latest `jquery 3.6.0` from official site, saved it locally in my static files like

`static/main_app/scripts/jQuery.js`

loaded it locally with

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main_app/scripts/jQuery.js' %}"></script>` 
in my `base.html`. This works and jQuery is working fine. But the Bootstrap's `nav-bar` buttons are not responding.
There is also not error message in browser's console.

So I though: Maybe the jQuery version is wrong?
So I tried to implement again working version to my site

`{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}`

, look for source of the file above in dev-tools of my browser, copy & pasted the source code to my `jQuery.js` file and loaded the site again. Nothing changed and the `navbar` still not working.

Is there something I'm missing?

*** UPDATE ***

It works when I set

```
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

but with

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
```

IT means I'm loading `bootstrap` two times...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overwrite `BOOTSTRAP4` pip package settings (jquery call) from CDN to local file in `settings.py` like this

```py
BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    "jquery_url": {
            "url": f"{STATIC_URL}main_app/scripts/jquery.js",
    },
}
```

Also [here](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) are another options to overwrite as well